# NextJS Error Page Custom CSS is Not Working

Tags: javascript, node.js, next.js

I generate 500 page in _error.js, when get errorCode ise 500 I want return special 500 page import.

There is no problem for my code, when user get 500 is saw my special 500 page, but css not working?

CSS is come in  tag but not working

Here is my _error.js code :

```
import React from 'react'
import Error from 'next/error'
import PageInternal from './500'

const MyError = ({ statusCode, hasGetInitialPropsRun, err }) => {

  return <Error statusCode={statusCode} />

  function Error({ statusCode }) {
    if (statusCode === 500) return <PageInternal />
  }
}

MyError.getInitialProps = async ({ res, err, asPath }) => {
  const errorInitialProps = await Error.getInitialProps({ res, err })
  const statusCode = res ? res.statusCode : err ? err.statusCode : 404
.... bla
}
```

CSS is not working, also JSX not working. I don't understand

[My custom 500 Component Pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pbB35.png)

[CSS not loading? Pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ynmo0.png)

My 500 component :

```
import React from 'react'
import DefaultLayout from 'components/layouts/default'
import './style.scss'

const PageInternal = (props) => {

  return (
    <DefaultLayout
      title="Problem"
      {...props}
    >
      <div className="page-internal">
        <div className="internal-image">500</div>
        <p>
          Technical Problems
        </p>
        <a className="btn btn-default btn-lg">Refresh Page</a>
      </div>
    </DefaultLayout>
  )
}
export default PageInternal
```

Comment: We'll need to see what's in `./500` as that's what get rendered. Could you update your question with that file?

Comment: @juliomalves I added pictures, pls help

Comment: Don't post images of code or error messages. Instead copy and paste or type the actual code/message into the post directly.

Comment: @juliomalves Ok, can you check again ?

Answer (score 1):

if you use styles.component, you need update Next.js to 10+ version. More details here https://github.com/vercel/next.js/issues/16931